# mule unit tests using maven surefire

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unit-testing, mule

when i run the unit tests from eclipse as junit tests its passing, but when tried to run using surefire plugin it is failing

```
INFO  2016-06-14 20:56:57,781 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising RegistryBroker
INFO  2016-06-14 20:56:57,973 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing RegistryBroker
INFO  2016-06-14 20:56:58,225 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising RegistryBroker
INFO  2016-06-14 20:56:58,230 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing RegistryBroker
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.704 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.company.munit.flows.devices.RetrieveDevicesMUnitTest
testGetDevicesWithOutQueryParamters(com.company.munit.flows.devices.RetrieveDevicesMUnitTest)  Time elapsed: 0.013 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: null (java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.mule.module.extension.internal.manager.DefaultExtensionManager.<init>(DefaultExtensionManager.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:473)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:508)
    at org.mule.util.ClassUtils.instanciateClass(ClassUtils.java:480)
    at org.mule.config.builders.ExtensionsManagerConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(ExtensionsManagerConfigurationBuilder.java:33)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager.createMule(MuleContextManager.java:106)
    at org.mule.munit.runner.functional.FunctionalMunitSuite.<init>(FunctionalMunitSuite.java:50)
    at com.company.munit.DefaultMUnit.<init>(DefaultMUnit.java:12)
    at com.company.munit.flows.devices.RetrieveDevicesMUnitTest.<init>(RetrieveDevicesMUnitTest.java:20)
```

Answer (score 1):

*(this should probably just be a comment but I am 4 rep short from being allowed to comment)*

When you run unit tests directly from Anypoint Studio (or any Eclipse based IDE) its builds the class path differently than when running those tests from Maven. Often Anypoint Studio will provide to the classpath things that you need even though your POM is not quite set up right. This is true more so recently with the release of APIKit which is not typically "provided" by the run time but often is provided by Anypoint Studio. This is exacerbated by the fact that some of the Mule dependencies erroneously depend on older versions of mule-core. Most notably APIKit and mule-munit-support. The problem is FURTHER enhanced by the recent EE only release of 3.7.4 in which we see that not ALL of the necessary components have gotten a 3.7.4 release even though many other components are depending on them.

If we could see more of your POM it would help us determine which dependency is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Maven POM declares this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I'm using mule.version 3.7.0 and this dependency also brings in junit-4.11. My tests run fine in Anypoint Studio and using Maven via the IDE or terminal. Be sure that this dependency is in your POM. Please let us know.